# Colorpicker not saving value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have added a color picker (http://jscolor.com/) input type to my website (on Wordpress + Gravity forms plugin) and it's not saving the color selection. I've played around with the input JS for a while and cant seem to fix the issue...

When the form is submitted all that is sent is #FFFFFF not the color actually selected.

Any ideas?

http://expressionwordart.pixelworklab.com/test-color

Comment: Why would you expect the color to remember its old value when you press previous?

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar is does not save when submitting either

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the color in a cookie when the user clicks next/previous and set the color from the cookie on page load.

Comment: It does not save if the user clicks submit on the next step either.. In other words if you select a color, go to the next step and click submit, the system just notifies me someone filled out the form and selected #FFFFFF for both colors.

Comment: I do not know what 'system just notifies' means, but I can seew that when next is clicked the values of the fields are sent in multipart/form-data:`-----------------------------59667122419457144161774146943

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="input_1"
ABFF3D
-----------------------------59667122419457144161774146943
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="input_2"
B3FF30`